# Discount showing without code

Tags: orders, backend, coupon

I have a client running Magento 1.7.0.2 and I have a question about the order display on the backend.

Some of the orders that have had discounts applied to them are showing the relevant discount code, and others aren't.

My question is: what would cause Magento to not display the coupon code next to the discount? Does this mean the coupon's been deleted?

I'ave attached a screenshot of the order rows and total boxes.

[image: Order totals]

Comment: Some discounts can be triggered without the use of coupon codes - you might want to post the relevant information of how the promotions have been set up.

Comment: Fooman is correct and because the code is saved in the order, deleting the rule for it won't remove the information from the order. I would guess, too, that you have a rule without code.

Comment: Thanks @FabianBlechschmidt, there was a discount configured without a code that could be to blame.